# EscapeDataString having differing behaviour between Powershell IDE and Powershell console

Tags: powershell, escaping, powershell-ise

I'm a bit confused with this issue! I'm building a bigger script and it was working in the ISE but not in a powershell console. I've managed to track it down to the [System.Uri]::EscapeDataString function which seems to be behaving differently between the different environments, for example in my powershell console () ' & ! are not being escaped, where as in the IDE they are all being escaped.

Am I missing something?

My test code:

```
[System.Uri]::EscapeDataString("/?:@%!$&'/*+,;=()")
```

ISE output:

```
%2F%3F%3A%40%25%21%24%26%27%2F%2A%2B%2C%3B%3D%28%29
```

Powershell Console output:

```
%2F%3F%3A%40%25!%24%26'%2F*%2B%2C%3B%3D()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: What is you PowerShell version. Be curious to check both shells to be sure you don't have switches used on your shortcuts. _Possible_ this is a bug but would need the version to be sure.

Comment: Reproducible on PowerShell 5 on Windows 10 and Windows 7.

Comment: @Matt 5.1.14393.693 Same on both consoles

Comment: Here is the difference: `[System.UriParser].GetField('s_QuirksVersion', [Reflection.BindingFlags] 'Static, NonPublic').GetValue($null)`.

Comment: @PetSerAl interesting, I don't see this quirksversion documented anywhere unless I'm missing something

Comment: @britcowboy There is always the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/a.html#c1b4c38749000c9b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the difference, per the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/a.html#c1b4c38749000c9b): `[System.UriParser].GetField('s_QuirksVersion', [Reflection.BindingFlags] 'Static, NonPublic').GetValue($null)`.

I marked the answer as community wiki because it appeared in the comments, causing the question to appear in searches for unanswered questions.

Comment: Is there any way to set this to V3 in PowerShell? (or V2 in ISE?) Some consistency would have saved me a couple of days of my life.