# Why does accessing a parameter variable's attributes with Get-Variable only work the first time in the ISE?

Tags: powershell, reflection, powershell-ise

Thanks to the great people at StackOverflow we received a very good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697072/find-the-values-in-validateset/42697469?noredirect=1#comment72520630_42697469) on how to retrieve the values defined in `ValidateSet` within the `Param()` clause of a script or function:

```
Param (
    [ValidateSet('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')]
    [String]$Type = 'Startup'
)

(Get-Variable Type).Attributes.ValidValues
```

The only thing that bothers me is that this code only works the **first time** when you run it in the PowerShell ISE. The **second time** you run it, there is no output generated.

Is there a workaround to have it always working? We use PowerShell 4.0 on Win 7 and Win 2012.

Comment: All panes in ISE are in the same scope. So basically if you want to get that again, you should remove it from the current shell scope and re-initialize it.

Comment: @DarkLite1 Be aware of [differences](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/04/17/differences-between-the-ise-and-powershell-console/) between ISE and powershell.exe. Some of them are quite [weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959310/escapedatastring-having-differing-behaviour-between-powershell-ide-and-powershel). Some can be explained due to [different configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime). ISE have best intellisense; otherwise Visual Studio Code, PowerGUI, or others are better and more predictable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- The **observed behavior is arguably a *bug***, present in Windows PowerShell and still as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.1- see [GitHub issue #3301](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3301).
- To **bypass the problem without side effects**, use the following approach:

```bash
Param (
    [ValidateSet('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')]
    [String] $Type = 'Startup'
)

$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters['Type'].Attributes.ValidValues
```

If there's a chance that `Set-StrictMode -version 2` or higher is in effect or you're using PSv2, use

```bash
Param (
    [ValidateSet('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')]
    [String] $Type = 'Startup'
)

($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters['Type'].Attributes |
  Where-Object { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute] }).ValidValues
```

---

#### Optional background information

The problem is not related to the *ISE* per se, but to **repeated *dot-sourcing*** (the ISE just happens to run all scripts by dot-sourcing them).

[Dot-sourcing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) runs scripts in the *current* scope (in the caller's scope itself, as opposed to in a child scope) and therefore typically modifies the current scope's state, such as by adding variables.
If you dot-source a script from an interactive session, you're effectively modifying the global session state, which is how definitions from the PS profile files are loaded, for instance.

In the case at hand, **a dot-sourced invocation of the script effectively adds *parameter* variable `$Type` to the invoking scope as a *regular* variable**, as designed.

**The bug surfaces when you dot-source the same script *again*** (assume that the script in the question is present as `./script.ps1`:

- After the first dot-sourced invocation, variable `$Type` is still intact with respect to its attribute:

  ```bash
    > . ./script.ps1; (Get-Variable Type).Attributes.Count
    Startup
    Shutdown
    LogOn
    LogOff
    3   # PS implicitly adds 2 add'l attributes behind the scenes
  ```
- When you dot-source *again*, the attributes are *lost*:

  ```bash
    > . ./script.ps1; (Get-Variable Type).Attributes.Count
    0
  ```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this behavior is only seen in PowerShell ISE (it works perfectly outside). This might be explained by the [following post](https://superuser.com/questions/777416/why-does-the-powershell-ise-not-isolate-script-variables-to-the-script-scope).

Reading it, you'll see that there is a workaround:

```
Param (
    [ValidateSet('Startup', 'Shutdown', 'LogOn', 'LogOff')]
    [String] $Type = 'Startup'
)

(Get-Variable Type).Attributes.ValidValues

# Do your stuff here

Remove-Variable Type
```

Comment: The behavior is a _bug_, and while it is most likely to surface in the ISE, it can surface in the regular console too, because it is related to repeated dot-sourcing.
`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Parameters['Type'].Attributes.ValidValues` is an alternative that bypasses the bug without the need for an extra `Remove-Variable` call, which is not only cumbersome, but has side effects.